# asp.net Identity 2.0 How to change connection string / DbContext at runtime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I would like to do the following in my MVC5, asp.net identity 2.0 app:

1. Change the connection string used by the ApplicationDBContext at runtime. I will have numerous clients, each with their own SQL database. So at session start, I need to be able to specify the desired database connection.
2. I assume to class ApplicationDbContext that I add the overload:

   ```
   public static ApplicationDbContext Create(string connectionString)
   {
       return new ApplicationDbContext(connectionString);
   }
   ```
3. I also am assuming that in Startup.Auth.cs that I need to modify this line to pass in the connection string. If so, then I am having troubles here with doing just that.

   ```
   app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
   ```

Am I going down the right road?  Am I missing anything else?  I am basically stuck at this point. TIA for your help.

Comment: Hi @chris did you find solution for this?any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: I took a different pathway and have not needed to follow-up on this issue. Sorry I don't have a working solution to share. But I think it is something should be made possible.

Comment: I made it worked, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change ApplicationDbContext to create an ApplicationDbContext instance with the proper connection string.  The Create is basically an ApplicationDbContext factory method.

Comment: any samples for this.

Answer (score 0):

Same question.

I have

```
public ApplicationDbContext() : base(@"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=mydata; integrated security=true")
```

and several other options that give me the same result. The 'hard coded' connection works just fine. But I need to set `initial catalog={somevariable}` such that I can get `{somevariable}` either from the user or from AspNetUser for the user who is logging in.

A code example would be really helpful. "Just do this" isn't so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a fix to use the constructor for initializing the connection string.
Just make a new contructor that takes you connectionstring, and fill it in the IdentityDbContext

```
 public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    public DbContext(string ConnectionString) : base(ConnectionString)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually occurs when you are using external SQL server instead of visual studio's SQL express. All you have to do is follow below steps:

1. Goto IdentityModels.cs .
2. In class ApplicationDbContext constructor place you connection string in place of "DefaultConnString" (First parameter of constructor).
3. Create a Empty DB in your server with name "ApplicationDbContext".
4. Now Run your application.

It should resolve by this.